# How to deploy an arbitrary binary to Nexus with maven

Tags: maven, nexus

I think I have run in to a maven deploy plugin bug, but I want to confirm that I am not doing it wrong before I open a bug report and start grepping through source.

I am trying to deploy an arbitrary binary (tar.gz,jar,box,etc) to a maven repository.
The user I am using is in the settings.xml file with a plaintext password.
The user is in an LDAP group that is connected to nexus with a Role.

That role has 3 privileges associated with it.  Update, Create, Read which are in turn associated with the repository target.

Now using wget the user can pull data from the repo, and using this curl command I can deploy to the repo:

```
curl --request PUT --user USERNAME:PASSWORD https://NEXUS_URL/nexus/content/repositories/REPO_NAME/path/to/file/with/groupid/version/iamafile.jar \
--data @./iamafile.jar  -H Content-Type:application/java-archive --verbose
```

This works fine, http 201 and the file is added.  When I use a similiar mvn deploy command:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file --settings /path/to/settings.xml \
-Durl=https://NEXUS_URL/nexus/content/repositories/REPOSITORYID -Dfile=iamafile.jar \
-DrepositoryId=REPOSITORYID -DartifactId=ARTIFACTID -DgroupId=GROUPID \
-Dversion=VERSION
```

I get an http 401 unauthorized error.

There have been [multiple](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-3048) [bug](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-4469) reports about this, but they supposedly have been fixed.
With a pom file with the same values for version, artifcatId, etc.  `mvn deploy` works fine.

Have I found a bug, or am I using it improperly?

Edit:

I opened up [this](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MDEPLOY-155?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel) bug regarding the issue.
If the dev's end up saying that it isn't a bug, I will add that as an answer if someone hasn't beat me to it.

Comment: Very odd that deploying with a POM works... I spend a lot of time troubleshooting Nexus 401 errors and they are almost always caused by not picking up credentials from the settings file (mismatching repository ids) or an incorrect username/password.

Comment: I was able to run it through Wireshark, and there was no Authentication header.

Comment: imho this should work. I would try without the --settings and just using the default settings.xml and putting the credentials there next..

Comment: Have you setup a security-settings.xml file ?  Then placed your <servers><server><password>... value in the server with the REPOSITORYID set in the <id> ?

Comment: I'm running into the same problem. Uploading via curl works. The deploy plugin definitively picks up the correct credentials (verified with -X) but I'm getting a 401. Did you ever find a way to fix this?

Comment: I just verified that it happens with Maven 3.0.5 but NOT with 3.0.3

Answer (score 1):

you need to additionally specify the -DrepositoryId